# where do the tables created using SQlite database will be stored in Android?

Tags: android

where do the tables created using SQlite database will be stored in Android?
how to access them and see the data contained in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android documentation explains it and the SDK provides a tool for accessing the database

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

there is additional information about db location in emulator here

[Where does Android emulator store SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database)