# i created a database in my app, but i don't find it in the DDMS

Tags: sql, android, database, ddms

I can't find my test.db in the file manager in DDMS. Does someone know when we create a database, where it's installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/data/data/package_name/databases
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a non-developer (or non-rooted) android device, the database will not be visible to you in DDMS. It's only visible to the parent application, as each application on android runs as a separate linux process.

However, if you are using the emulator or a developer/rooted device, the database file should be in `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/` ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)).