# sqlite browser: where is the db file?

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like examine androids internal database files using a sqlite browser. From my understanding contacts, etc. is stored in an sql lite db on Android. Now I want to read these tables using sqlite browser. For that I need to specify the db file, but where is it located?

The question is where is the location for the emulator?

Where is it located on a real device?

Can I access it on a real device which is not rooted?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All databases are saved in:

```
/data/data/the.app.package.name/databases/the_name_of_db
```

And no, you cannot access that file in a non-rooted phone. Fortunately the emulator *is rooted*.

Comment: Actually, you can access that location on a non-rooted phone, if you've enabled "USB debugging" under "developer options" and connected the device by USB cable to a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Open your application with emulator and go in DDMS. Then in FileExplorer go into data/data/application.package.name/databases/name_of_your_database. Then pull it from device