# How to find and clear the SQLite db file in Android (emulator)

Tags: android, sqlite

I've just got my first SQLite database up and running but to reproduce it I wanted a quick way to clear the db file (so I can call my `openOrCreateDatabase` method again)

First question: I see all over the web `/data/data/PKG/databases/` but where exactly is this stored on a windows machine? It doesn't appear to be in my local project folder because when I do a simple `git status`, no `*.db` file is listed after the create is successful.

Also if I wanted to clear this is it a simple delete and the emulator will know to re create this? If not how can I clear it from the emulator? (thinking iPhone here where you had to delete and re-push the app to the simulator to clear this out and have the db re-created)

Comment: Your First Question Answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's stored inside the emulator, not on your machine (at least, not in a place that is easily accessible).  Just remove it using `adb`:

```
C:\> adb -e shell rm /data/data/com.example.package/databases/*.db
```

You can also choose the "Wipe user data" option when launching the emulator AVD, or you can uninstall the application to wipe all data for just that one app:

```
C:\> adb -e uninstall com.example.package
```

Finally, you can also just clear user data for a given application without uninstalling it, by going to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications...  Select your application, then click the "Clear Data" button.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open **Simulator**
2. Click **MENU**
3. Click **Manage Apps**
4. Locate your app
5. Click **Clear data** or **Uninstall**

Comment: For my emulator (API 24) the route is: `App drawer` > `Settings` > `Apps` > `(Your App)` > `Storage` > `CLEAR DATA`.

Answer (score 5):

1)Its actually stored in the emulator, If you are using Eclipse then You just go to DDMS and find your database file in the data packages and then in the left there is an option to pull the file out and you can view it. you can use wipe user data on emulator load to clear all data.Or you may uninstall the application by using:

```
C:\> adb -e uninstall com.example.package
```

or, if your application is on a physical phone, use:

```
C:\> adb -d uninstall com.example.package
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run the command:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell (or whatever port you use)
cd /data/data/<packagename>/databases/
```

By typing ls, you will see the databases created and you can remove the one you want with rm

```
rm myapp.db
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 3):

Using AVD Manager to clear virtual device data is another option.

After opening avd manager by choosing Tools->AVD Manager,

Virtual device data can be cleared by clicking Menu-> Wipe Data.

It is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To clear the Database file from Emulator:

Go to DDMS, then go to file explorer then open data -> data -> urPackage-> urDatabase.

Here you have your database, and you can delete it by: 
(selecting)Click the database that you want to delete and click minus "-" sign from top right.