# Ionic 2: Get size cache directory and clear it

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I use [cordova-plugin-file](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) for ionic 2.

I know the path of the cache directory, here is my code:

```
this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(this.file.cacheDirectory).then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) ;
});
```

Is it possible in Ionic to know a directory's size and clear all files in it?

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
this.file.listDir(this.file.cacheDirectory,'').then((result)=>{
    for(let file of result){
        if(file.isFile == true){

            if(deleteFiles == 1) this.file.removeFile(this.file.cacheDirectory, file.name) ;
            else {
                file.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
                    let name = file.name ;
                    let size = metadata.size ;
                    console.log('Name: ' + name + ' / Size: ' + size) ;
                    sizes += size ;
                    }) ;
                }
        }
    }
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.You have to use below methods.

`getFreeDiskSpace()` - Get free disk space in Bytes

> Returns: Promise Returns a promise that resolves with the
>   remaining free disk space in Bytes

`removeRecursively(path, dirName)` - Removes all files and the directory from a desired location.

> path  string   Base FileSystem. Please refer to the iOS and Android
>   filesystems above
>
> dirName   string   Name of directory
>
> Returns:
>   Promise Returns a Promise that resolves with a
>   RemoveResult or rejects with an error.

Official [**doc is here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/).

Comment: I need to know size `cacheDirectory`

Comment: You can get the free disk space and according to that, you have to adjust your requirement.

Comment: I have a question, if i erase the cacheDirectory this erase the sqlite database ?

Comment: Where you installed it? @JorgeMejia

Comment: Well I use cordova-sqlite-storage plugin for Android but the documentation not specify where is installed the database.

Comment: OK, then it stores in `/data/data/[packagename]/databases` android.You can see more here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227110/android-where-is-sqlite-database-stored @JorgeMejia

Comment: In other words, you need to uninstall the app to remove SQLite. @JorgeMejia