# How to open an SQL database file for an already existing app on android?

Tags: android, sql

I want to see the database of one of my apps on my phone without root and without using android studio. How is it possible to do this?

Ps. I have a basic programming knowledge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227110/android-where-is-sqlite-database-stored

Comment: Which dbms? Different products have different possibilities.

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess it's relational.