# Running SQLite in AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-sqlite

I'm trying to use a DB SQLite in my app and I'm having troubles. Android is returning an app crash saying "forced close" when I try to run the app, I've checked the code to see if values and returns are ok and it seems to be, made some debugs and the problem is clearly on the createDataBase method. He needs to find the location of the DB, I've passed in a variable PATH and even that still crashs, don't know if it's correct cause to run directly on the tablet I need to make a different path  like data/data.... (discovered that researching, not sure) and on AVD (that's the problem) I need to specify where the DB is on my desktop?

take a look at the code:

ConnectDB

```
   package com.victor.profile;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.victor.profile.MainActivity;

public class ConnectDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "C:/Users/Victor/Dropbox/workspace/Profile/database";

    private static String DB_NAME = "profile_db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    Dialog dialog;

    boolean  dbalert;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public ConnectDB(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            dbalert = new MainActivity().dbFail();

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.victor.profile;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void RegisterActivity(View view) throws IOException{

        Intent intent = new Intent (this, RegisterActivity.class);
        ConnectDB dbcreator = new ConnectDB(this);
        dbcreator.createDataBase();
        startActivity(intent);  
    }



    public boolean dbFail(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Closing App");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Unable to find Database...");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              onDestroy();
           }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here it's the logcat erros

```
08-06 17:44:09.915: I/Database(283): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
*08-06 17:44:09.915: E/Database(283): sqlite3_open_v2("profile_db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed*
08-06 17:44:09.925: D/AndroidRuntime(283): Shutting down VM
08-06 17:44:09.925: W/dalvikvm(283): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
*08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.victor.profile.MainActivity.RegisterActivity(MainActivity.java:36)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  ... 11 more
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:743)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:273)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.victor.profile.MainActivity.dbFail(MainActivity.java:43)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.victor.profile.ConnectDB.checkDataBase(ConnectDB.java:83)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.victor.profile.ConnectDB.createDataBase(ConnectDB.java:47)
08-06 17:44:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  ... 15 more
08-06 17:44:09.965: W/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.victor.profile/.MainActivity
08-06 17:44:10.315: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x342d00:0x342dbc] in 385721 ns
08-06 17:44:10.525: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44fee218 com.victor.profile/.MainActivity}
08-06 17:44:20.796: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44fee218 com.victor.profile/.MainActivity}*
```

Comment: You need to post the logcat error.  If there is a forced close you should see in red a fatal exception.  Post the first five lines of code after fatal.

Comment: If you don't see logcat goto windows->showview->logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a path to your hard drive in the emulator like this:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "C:/Users/Victor/Dropbox/workspace/Profile/database";
```

The emulator creates an environment that mimics a real device as much as possible. It has it's own file structure and your approach is incorrect. Instead use this to create a database:

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

If you want to access your database in the emulator read this: [Where does Android emulator store SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510840/1267661)

**New LogCat**

When you call `new ConnectDB(this)` the SQLiteOpenHelper class creates the database for you. You don't need your method createDataBase().

And when you use getReadableDatabase() like this:

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
}
catch(SQLiteException exception) {
    // Database didn't open, exit app gracefully
}
```

Then you don't need your checkDataBase() method either, both of the processes are done already by SQLite.

**Lastly** you don't need to exit your app in onDestory(). Trying to close an app that is closing is redundant. Also if you ever want to close an app use the Android method `finish()`. Always use the Android commands over a standard Java command.

Comment: I will try your link, hope it solve my problem, thanks dude, in fews minutes I will be back to answer, thank you

Comment: I've correted what you've said but still not working, the app still crashs =/ don't you have any ideas more of what should be?

Comment: The best way to know what is happening is to read the LogCat. Open the LogCat window in Eclipse, highlight the red error rows, press Crtl+C, click "edit" in the lower left of your question, paste the LogCat errors into your questions, re-highlight the errors is your question, and press Crtl+K to format the LogCat errors for Stack Overflow. (It might sound confusing but it's simple.)