# where is data/data file location in phone

Tags: android

i store my file in this location for picture hiding File file = new File("/data/data/com.vault.vaultpckg/Files");  is work fine but after somw pics hide low memory alert come so tel my where is this file path in phone device? i wanna see file location of data/data/applcation folder what do i do?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.file);
 list_Files = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.file_list);

File file = new File("/data/data/com.vault.vaultpckg/Files");
file.mkdir();
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking...

Comment: refer to the answer by rogcg   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't assume anything about data/data.  Use the getDir function on Activity to get your local directory.  Also, you cannot open files in any other app, so using a full pathname is kind of pointless.

Comment: but where is this file create in phone memory? is work thats y i ask

Answer (score 0):

To see the contents of the /data/data folder on a real device, you need to have a rooted device and be using a file explorer with root privileges.

When using the emulator, you should be able to see it using the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.