# How to refresh database on android emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am very new to android programming.

I deployed my search app which has a database to the emulator.

Then I make some changes to the data in the code in Eclipse, and run the project as Android Application.

The data shown in the emulator is still the old data.

How can I see the new data without restarting the emulator and checking Wipe User Data?
It takes very long to start the emulator.

Comment: Database need not to be manually refreshed . it will reflect the change automatically

Comment: You can either delete the database from your code itself and recrete it , Thats simple

Comment: Use Genymotion (https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/customer/login/?next=/) or the older version AndroVM (http://androvm.org/blog/download/) . Much faster than the SDK's emulator, but it's x86. So you won't get THAT close emulating a real phone, but it's much faster to test changes. And Genymotion got accelerometer and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see data follow this link: [Where does Android emulator store SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database)

Just remove it using `adb`:

```
C:\> adb -e shell rm /data/data/com.example.package/databases/*.db
```

You can also choose the "Wipe user data" option when launching the emulator AVD, or you can uninstall the application to wipe all data for just that one app:

```
C:\> adb -e uninstall com.example.package
```

Finally, you can also just clear user data for a given application without uninstalling it, by going to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications...  Select your application, then click the "Clear Data" button.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to remove previous database in android.

```
Go to android Emulator setting--> Application --> your Application (click on it) >> clear data.
```

Thanks