# Where does Android emulator store Password?

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device, ddms

I want see emulator password and save in a text file with adb.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database) question but i can't find correct folder in DDMS,
Please help me.

what command i need to do this work?

Comment: do  you want to see squlite data of emulator like password???

Comment: yes i want see password squlite and save in text file and change this password.

Comment: ok..,wait...give me 2 minutes .,i show you answer.

Comment: please see this pictuer http://www.shiaupload.ir/images/24159574315543946370.png

Comment: ya i have given you that solution..,you will understand clerly now,,..:)

Comment: then please accept my answer by ticking it..

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
1.Open File Explore...

2.then go to data------>data........>then your package name(project packeage name)
```

see here [image]

```
3. in your packege there is a folder "Database" ,in this folder your database is saved.

4.then pull this database file on your system.,where you want to save this .

5.Open Squlite Browser.,and open your database file..,then you can see your password or any filed.
```

Comment: thanks but i want work with adb this solution is in Squlite Browser. How can i access to squlite in adb??

Comment: see heer http://www.dormantroot.com/2011/08/accessing-sqlite-from-android-debug.html