# How to find sqlite file on Android simulator?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to find `Android Device Monitor` on my Android Studio to open my sqlite file, but I can't find `Android Device Monitor`.
[image]

I find official document says that has been depreciated.
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

But I still can't find the way how to open my sqlite file on the android simulator.

My Android Studio version is 3.1.4

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database

Comment: There is no `Android device monitor` under Tools.

Comment: Just FYI - Android *Emulator*, not *Simulator*. Apple provides the *Simulator*, because it actually does not *Emulate* the iOS device. While Google's Emulator emulates the Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 3.1.1 At Right side corner you have a tab called **Device File Explorer**
In That go to data/data find your application package name in tha folder will be there name database there you will find sqlite file.

[image: My Android Studio View]

Comment: I find it now ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You will find **"DEVICE FILE EXPLORER"**
refer screen shot below  [image]

> Choose Data->Data->YOUR PROJECT PACKAGE NAME->databases

You will find your .db/.sqlite file there

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I find it now.

Answer (score 1):

Click **View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer** or click the Device File Explorer button in the tool window bar to open the Device File Explorer.

Select a device from the drop down list.

Interact with the device content in the file explorer window.

Right-click on a file or directory to create a new file or directory, save the selected file or directory to your machine, upload, delete, or synchronize. Double-click a file to open it in Android Studio

database path is commonly ...**/data/data/packagename/databases/**

[image]